# C# Date Field DataBinding Value to String

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Im getting from database 2 date fields in string format like:

**"yyyy.mm.dd"**

Then, In my form I want to add DataBinding to the 2 DatePickers that will show these dates like below:

```
dtStart.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", _ds.Tables["invoice"], "startdate"));
dtEnd.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", _ds.Tables["invoice"], "enddate"));
```

The problem right now is that when I change the date from the DatePicker then the Value will be a Date and what I need is to update the value but in the same string format "yyyy.mm.dd".

Any clue how can I force to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have any so-called `format string`. If you want to display a `DateTime`, you have to convert it to string with some format (such as `yyyy.mm.dd`)

Comment: The dates are shown correctly in the Datepickers, what I need is the opposite, when I change the Datepicker obviously the datatable cell value will be updated with a DateTime instead of a formatted string.

Comment: the `Value` of `DateTimePicker` is a `DateTime` , so why can a `formatted string` be updated back to your `DataTable`? You should check the `DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format`

Comment: It's not possible to override when the DataBinding updates the value back to the datatable? So there I can do value = bindingvalue.ToString("yyyy.mm.dd")?

Comment: You want the value updated back to your DataTable to be a formatted string with format `yyyy.mm.dd`? Unless you define your `DataGridViewColumn` as type of string. Otherwise (type of DateTime), you should check out the `DataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format` to show the datetime in the format you want.

Comment: Exactly, Im updating the value using a Datepicker not inside the grid. What about configuring the DataColumn to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DataGridViewColumn `startdate` is type of `string`. You can add code to the `Parse` event handler of a `Binding` to format the value before updating back to the DataSource:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Value", _ds.Tables["invoice"], "startdate");
bind.Parse += (s,e) => {
   e.Value = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToString("yyyy.mm.dd");
};
dtStart.DataBindings.Add(bind);
//Do the same for dtEnd
```

However, I recommend setting your `DataGridViewColumn data type` as `DateTime`. Then you won't need any custom `Parsing` and just set the format for the cells in that column like this:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["startdate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy.mm.dd";
```

Comment: Let me try it...!! sound like this is the solution :) Thanks

Comment: Yes it worked nice!! I was trying to find that solution long long time ago. Appreciate it